# Deleting the insides of model/ hollowing it

Tags: modeling

Hi i'd like to ask if i can delete all the faces and vertices from in side my model,

Here's my model, it looks fine, but there's problems, like some parts of it have two faces so it sort of glitches. (near the back of the foot)

[image: My model]

And also, i used ALT + E to extrude individual faces, that made all of inside of it just horrible, and i want that the whole model to be hollow in the inside, like so

This is a cube
[image: Cube inside]

And this, is inside of my model,

[image: My model]

So, my question is, can i delete all this messy blocks inside of it without any noticeable changes on the outside?

Also, i'm sort of new to blender so please tell me what you mean and how i would do it. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try *Remove Doubles*?

Comment: Don't know how to do that. Sorry, i am new to blender. I'll edit it saying i'm new because don't want this to happen big time again.

Comment: Select all vertices in Edit mode (press `A` to do that) and then press `W` *> Remove Doubles*

Comment: Didn't work. just deleted random bits on the side of the model.

Comment: Just noticed, you have your Normals all calculated wrong. Select all vertices and press `Ctrl`+`N`.

Comment: Oh, i see, sorry for the duplicated post, i searched for 1 and a half days for a answer on the internet, damn. I'll try what they have there, also, what do you mean my normals? Sorry for not knowing what normals are but i don't EDIT: I tried what they said, didn't work for me.

Comment: Normals basically tell which direction a face is pointing, right now they are all pointing inwards. Selecting all vertices in edit mode and pressing `Ctrl`+`N` will fix that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20579/discussion-between-rielight-and-noviceindisguise).

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise With all the wacked-up, non-manifold geometry in the model, recalculating normals won't do much of anything useful.

Comment: How do you determine if a face is interior or not though? By normals?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Select Inner Faces* operator,  and then delete then. To do this, in 3D view space, go to the header, then *Select*, then *Interior Faces*. Then you can press <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices*.

Comment: That doesn't work for this sort of model. I am giving up on this model now after a long chat with someone, but i'll keep this place up for anyone who might have the same problem as me.